# Enviar input del formulario a Controlador con angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs

Necesito enviar la colección de inputs del formulario al método controlador MVC (C#) por medio de una petición ajax desde un controlador de Angular, el problema es que el **FormCollection** llega vacío al controlador.

¿Cómo puedo enviar el formulario serializado por medio de angularJS?

Es una vista con controles generados dinámicamente y no utilizo un ViewModel necesito la colección de FormControll.

```
<input="button" ng-click="submit()" />

//submit Angular controlador:
$scope.submit = function () {
$http({
        url: '/Tickets/Update',
        method: "POST",
        data: --> aqui el formulario serializdo JSON

    })
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
}
```

Gracias

Comment: Debes incluir el código que has escrito hasta ahora para poder reproducir el problema. Como construyes el formulario y como lo estas intentando enviar.

Answer (score 1):

No deberias usar el FormCollection si usas angular, se supone que debes generar un json que mapee con el parametro que del model que defines en el action, de esta forma el DataBinding hara el resto, si la propiedad de json mapea con la propiedad de la clase del model asignara el valor.

[AngularJS $http service in an ASP.NET MVC app](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/angularjs/1202/angular-http-service-aspnet-mvc)

La idea es que desde angular tengas una json que represente el model de la view que puedas bindear a los controles de la view y asi poder mantener los datos sincronizados.

Luego tomas este y lo envias a un service que hara uso de `$http` para enviar en el post este json al action

Todo esto lo observaras en el articulo que sugiero, pero no se usa para nada el FormCollection